# Wrap segment with slashes in Sublime T3 (PHP or JS)

Tags: javascript, php, sublimetext3, comments

Is it possible to wrap a segment og code or text with slashes (so that it will be commented out) in Sublime with some kind of plugin? I can't seem to get Emmet to do so..

An example of what i'm aiming for:

```
//////////////////////////////
// Comment out in PHP or JS //
//////////////////////////////
```

And I'm obviously aware of the fact that this can be done manually - but it's time consuming. :-)

Comment: I don't know if there is a plugin for that prupose. I think it would be much easier making a snippet than a plugin.

Comment: This sample snippet wraps the selected text (no more than one line)  with slashes: 
`<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
///${SELECTION/^ +(.)|(.) +$|(.)/\//g}///
// ${SELECTION/^ +(.)|(.) +$|(.)/\1\2\3/g} //
///${SELECTION/^ +(.)|(.) +$|(.)/\//g}///
]]></content>
</snippet>`